# Excel average rows to array formula

Tags: arrays, excel, average, array-formulas

I want to take the average of rows which would result in a column (array). Example input:

3 4

4 4

4 6

With an array formula I want to create:

3.5

4

5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The average is the sum of numbers divided by the count of that numbers.
So first add them (A1:A3+B1:B3)
3+4 = 7
4+4 = 8
4+6 = 10
Then divide by the number of numbers(/2):
7/2 = 3.5
8/2 = 4
10/2 = 5

```
{=(A1:A3+B1:B3)/2}
```

edit after comment from op:
formula for addition without adding column manually from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Q9x44sclzfY

```
{=mmult(A1:B3,sign(transpose(column(A1:B3))))/Columns(A1:B3)}
```

Comment: I mean to use only array A1:B3 as input otherwise it does not work for my purpose.. :(

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do that in Excel

`=SUBTOTAL(1,OFFSET(A1:B3,ROW(A1:B3)-MIN(ROW(A1:B3)),0,1))`

`OFFSET` supplies an "array of ranges", each range being a single row, and `SUBTOTAL` with 1 as first argument, averages each of those ranges. You can use this in another formula or function or entered in a range on the worksheet.

The advantage over Siphor's suggestion with `MMULT` is that this will still work even with blanks or text values in the range (those will be ignored)

Answer (score 1):

Excel for 365 and Excel Online have the `BYROW` and `BYCOL` functions now. To perform the same function as above, just use the following formula:

```
=BYROW(A1:B3, LAMBDA(row, AVERAGE(row)))
```

[BYROW function - Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb)

To put it simply, the `BYROW` and `BYCOL` functions apply the supplied `LAMBDA` function to each row in the array. In this case, the provided `LAMBDA` function applies the `AVERAGE` function to each of its inputs. Since `BYROW` supplies each row of the array, `AVERAGE` is applied to each row.

Answer (score -1):

If first column is A and the second is B, then enter this formuls in column C:

```
=AVERAGE(A1,B1)
```

and extend it to the last row

Also you can use a range if you have more than 2 columns (this function allows for some cells to be empty):

```
 =AVERAGE(A1:F1)
```

Comment: sorry I mean i want to use an array formula for this which calculates per row the average and stores it in a new array... (selecting the two columns as input and using CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to generate the last column)